# Obtener el maximo valor para cada propiedad desde un objeto de objetos

Tags: javascript, objeto, foreach, reduce

Hola Comunidad espero esten bien. Tengo que reducir un objeto de objetos y obtener solo 1 objeto con los valores máximos para cada propiedad, por ejemplo

Mi objeto input es de este tipo:

```
input: {
    "2.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 88,
            "y": 231
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 79,
            "y": 175
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": -3,
            "y": 22
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": -2,
            "y": 2
        }
    },
    "1.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 324
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 99,
            "y": 509
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 14
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 25
        }
    }
}
```

y el objeto final que necesito es de este tipo:

```
output:{
 "prop1": {
   "x": 88, //porque es el mayor valor de la prop entre los objetos 1.0 y 2.0 
   "y": 324 //porque es el mayor  entre los objetos 1.0 y 2.0 
 },
 "prop2": {
   "x": 99,
   "y": 509
  },
 "prop3": {
   "x": 3,
   "y": 22
  },
 "prop4": {
   "x": 4,
   "y": 25
  },
}
```

La idea es obtener para cada propiedad entre varios objetos el valor máximo entre ellos y obtener 1 objeto final con todas las propiedades con el valor máximo entre todos los objetos.

Actualmente intento con un reduce y luego un foreach pero no puedo obtener el resultado final correctamente.

```
Object.values(input).reduce((highestValues, objData) => {
  Object.entries(objData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const highest = highestValues[key]; 
    if (highest === undefined || highest > value) {
      highestValues[key] = value
    }
  })
  return highestValues
}, {});
```

Comment: Agrega lo que has logrado hasta ahora.

Comment: Como te comentan, debes añadir lo que has intentado, mediante un [mcve]. De lo contrario parece que buscas que lo hagan por ti. Saludos

Comment: Buenas estimado, agrega lo que haz intentado.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con la instrucción [**`for...in`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) para recorrer los objetos y usar el método [**`Math.max()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) para mostrar el máximo de los valores de cada `prop`:

```js
const input = {
    "2.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 88,
            "y": 231
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 79,
            "y": 175
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": -3,
            "y": 22
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": -2,
            "y": 2
        }
    },
    "1.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 324
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 99,
            "y": 509
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 14
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 25
        }
    }
};

const output = {}; // aquí se almacenarán los objetos con los valores máximos.

for (const prop in input["1.0"]) { // recorro el objeto y le asignamos a una constante llamada "prop".
    output[prop] = { // creamos nuevos objetos dentro del objeto "output".
        // estos objetos tendrán claves ("x" y "y") y los valores serán los máximos de las claves "1.0" y "2.0" de "input"
        x: Math.max(input["1.0"][prop].x, input["2.0"][prop].x), // busco el mayor entre "x" y "y" de cada "prop" entre las claves "1.0" y "2.0", el mayor guardo en "x", así para cada objeto que se irá generando en "output"
        y: Math.max(input["1.0"][prop].y, input["2.0"][prop].y) // busco el mayor entre "x" y "y" de cada "prop" entre las claves "1.0" y "2.0", el mayor guardo en "y", así para cada objeto que se irá generando en "output"
    };
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas dejo aqui para compartir una linda solucion que obtuve de otro usuario de la comunidad:

```
const data = { "2.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 88,
            "y": 231
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 79,
            "y": 175
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": -3,
            "y": 22
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": -2,
            "y": 2
        }
    },
    "1.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 324
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 99,
            "y": 509
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 14
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 25
        }
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(data).reduce((carry, current) => {
    Object.entries(current).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        Object.entries(value).forEach(([k,v]) => {
            if (!carry[key]) {
                carry[key] = {}
            }
            carry[key][k] = Math.max(carry[key][k], v);
        });
    });
    return carry;
}));
```

Comment: Recuerda verificar la respuesta que te sirvió marcándolo con un ✔️, así tu pregunta estará como respondida, saludos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Querido Cristian: No se observa ningún error en el código proporcionado. Sin embargo, hay algunas prácticas ineficientes que se podrían mejorar. Por ejemplo, en lugar de recorrer el objeto "input" con un ciclo for-in, se podría utilizar el método Object.keys para obtener una lista de las propiedades del objeto y luego utilizar un ciclo for-of para recorrer la lista de propiedades. Esto ayudaría a mejorar la legibilidad y claridad del código. Además, se podría utilizar el método Object.entries para obtener una lista de las propiedades y sus valores en lugar de acceder a cada propiedad del objeto por separado.

```
const input = {
    "2.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 88,
            "y": 231
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 79,
            "y": 175
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": -3,
            "y": 22
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": -2,
            "y": 2
        }
    },
    "1.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 324
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 99,
            "y": 509
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 14
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 25
        }
    }
};

const output = {}; // aquí se almacenarán los objetos con los valores máximos.

const keys = Object.keys(input["1.0"]); // obtenemos una lista de las propiedades del objeto "input"

for (const key of keys) { // recorremos la lista de propiedades con un ciclo for-of
    // obtenemos una lista de las propiedades y sus valores para cada "key"
    const [x1, y1] = Object.entries(input["1.0"][key]);
    const [x2, y2] = Object.entries(input["2.0"][key]);

    // creamos nuevos objetos dentro del objeto "output".
    // estos objetos tendrán claves ("x" y "y") y los valores serán los máximos de las claves "1.0" y "2.0" de "input"
    output[key] = {
        x: Math.max(x1, x2), // buscamos el mayor valor de "x" para cada "key" en las claves "1.0" y "2.0"
        y: Math.max(y1, y2) // buscamos el mayor valor de "y" para cada "key" en las claves "1.0" y "2.0"
    };
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: tu entiendes, que esto no es una red social, que "cristian" no se entera de tu respuesta, y que quien pregunta y espera una respuesta, no es cristian.. y que dejar 4 respuestas en una pregunta, esta mal!!

Answer (score -2):

Como va joven internauta, me gusta mucho tu pregunta. Podes usar una combinación de reduce() y Object.entries() para obtener el resultado que queres.

La idea es iterar sobre cada uno de los objetos en input, y para cada propiedad en cada objeto, comparar su valor con el valor máximo actual para esa propiedad. Si el valor del objeto actual es mayor, se actualiza el valor máximo para esa propiedad en el objeto final.

Para hacer esto, podes usar Object.entries() para obtener un array de pares clave-valor para cada propiedad en el objeto actual, y luego usar reduce() para iterar sobre ese array y comparar cada valor con el valor máximo actual para esa propiedad en el objeto final.

Aca te doy un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementar esto:

```
const input = {
    "2.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 88,
            "y": 231
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 79,
            "y": 175
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": -3,
            "y": 22
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": -2,
            "y": 2
        }
    },
    "1.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 324
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 99,
            "y": 509
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 14
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 25
        }
    }
};

// Usamos reduce() para iterar sobre cada uno de los objetos en input
const output = Object.values(input).reduce((highestValues, objData) => {
  // Para cada propiedad en el objeto actual, obtenemos un array de pares clave-valor
  // con Object.entries()
  const entries = Object.entries(objData);

  // Usamos reduce() de nuevo para iterar sobre el array de entradas y comparar
  // cada valor con el valor máximo actual para esa propiedad en el objeto final
  entries.reduce((highestValues, [key, value]) => {
    const highest = highestValues[key];
    if (highest === undefined || highest > value) {
      // Si el valor del objeto actual es mayor, actualizamos el valor máximo
      // para esa propiedad en el objeto final
      highestValues[key] = value;
    }
    return highestValues;
  }, highestValues);

  return highestValues;
}, {});

console.log(output);
// Debería mostrar:
// {
//   "prop1": {
//     "x": 88,
//     "y": 324
//   },
//   "prop2": {
//     "x": 99,
//     "y": 509
//   },
//   "prop3": {
//     "x": 3,
//     "y": 22
//   },
//   "prop4": {
//     "x": 4,
//     "y": 25
//   }
// }
```

Comment: A mí me muestra el primero objeto `2.0`

Comment: Buenas! muchas gracias por la respuesta señor! Si a mi tambien me muestra el 2.0

Answer (score -2):

Si estás obteniendo el primer objeto en lugar del objeto final que queres, es posible que esté ocurriendo porque en el código, estás iterando sobre el array de entradas con entries.reduce() en lugar de iterar sobre el array con entries.forEach().

La función reduce() es utilizada para reducir un array a un solo valor, mientras que forEach() es utilizada para iterar sobre un array y realizar una acción para cada elemento del array.

En este caso, para iterar sobre el array de entradas y comparar cada valor con el valor máximo actual para esa propiedad en el objeto final, tenes q usar forEach() en lugar de reduce().

Aca tenes una versión del código que utiliza forEach() en lugar de reduce() para iterar sobre el array de entradas y obtener el resultado que queres:

```
const input = {
    "2.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 88,
            "y": 231
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 79,
            "y": 175
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": -3,
            "y": 22
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": -2,
            "y": 2
        }
    },
    "1.0": {
        "prop1": {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 324
        },
        "prop2": {
            "x": 99,
            "y": 509
        },
        "prop3": {
            "x": 3,
            "y": 14
        },
        "prop4": {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 25
        }
    }
};

// Usamos reduce() para iterar sobre cada uno de los objetos en input
const output = Object.values(input).reduce((highestValues, objData) => {
  // Para cada propiedad en el objeto actual, obtenemos un array de pares clave-valor
  // con Object.entries()
  const entries = Object.entries(objData);

  // Usamos forEach() para iterar sobre el array de entradas y comparar
  // cada valor con el valor máximo actual para esa propiedad en el objeto final
  entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
    const highest = highestValues[key];
    if (highest === undefined || highest > value) {
      // Si el valor del objeto actual es mayor, actualizamos el valor máximo
      // para esa propiedad en el objeto final
      highestValues[key] = value;
    }
  });

  return highestValues;
}, {});

console.log(output);
// Debería mostrar:
// {
//   "prop1": {
//     "x": 88,
//     "y": 324
//   },
//   "prop2": {
//     "x": 99,
//     "y": 509
//   },
//   "prop3": {
//     "x": 3,
//     "y": 22
//   },
//   "prop4": {
//     "x": 4,
//     "y": 25
//   }
// }
```

Comment: Tenías que editar tu respuesta, no agregar otra nueva.

Comment: Hola Cris!, deje las dos para que otro lo use si le sirve mas! espero que lo hayas podido entender el tema y para lo que necesites estoy con vos. Tengo mucha facilidad para esto :) saludos

Comment: Ninguno de los dos traen el resultado esperado.

Comment: No estoy aca para hacer el trabajo a nadie. Solo para mostrar como se hace, despues cada uno lo tiene que adaptar a su proyecto. Saludos

Comment: Pues tu muestra de "cómo se hace" es erróneo.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Este usuario parece sospechoso de generar respuestas con Chat GPT, o alguna otra herramienta de respuestas genericas o automatizadas.

Comment: Perdon? tu respuesta tiene que resolver el problema.. no quedar, cerca, y no, no se ponen dos respuestas, ni 3, ni 4.. es una respuesta a una pregunta.